# Magento 1.9.4.0 suddenly stops working with PHP 7.2, needed to downgrade to PHP 5.6

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, php-7.2

We changed our PHP to 7.2 a week ago. There were no problems but suddenly after a week there was a problem. Users were redirected to the cart after pressing the "Confirm Order" button on Checkout page and the order was not submitted.

I fixed it by changing back to `PHP 5.6`.

There were no errors in the logfiles, the server error log had no info as well. I just noticed that the form key did not changed?

There werent any code changes too.

Did anyone encountered the same problem and has found a solution?

Comment: Where you able to find any errors in your browser console or in network tab response?

Comment: Yes Network tab showed a 500 error after clicking the confirm order button, but there were not further infos. I cant retest it unfortunately

Comment: I have also faced a similar issue in Magento 1 when an order is placed users are being redirected to cart page with 500 error in console. I found the issue was to be with PHP configuration memory_limit. The site was working fine for days with a memory_limit of 256 MB but suddenly the error has blocked the place order. So check php confguration limits. Are you getting this error only in your live server?

Comment: Memory limit is set to 2 GB, so I don't think this is the issue. I only tested on the live server unfortunately.

Comment: Mostly the issue must be related with configuration values. Unless we have exact error message it will be very difficult for us to trace the issue